# Docusign SDK V3 createRecipientView - INVALID_REQUEST_BODY

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

I am having trouble implementing the DocuSign Node Client (SDK v3). I am using the Docusign examples on GitHub and NPM, but keep getting INVALID_REQUEST_BODY when calling createRecipeintView.

I login successfully and create an envelope with createEnvelope. Most of the examples to create an envelope use the SDK v2 signature for the second parameter of the method.

```
envelopesApi.createEnvelope(accountId, envDef, ...
```

SDK v3 on the NPM site wraps the second parameter as follows

```
envelopesApi.createEnvelope(accountId, {'envelopeDefinition': envDef}, ...
```

I would like to know how the 3rd parameter is wrapped for the envelopesApi.createRecipientView method on the SDK v3.

The examples of the SDK version 2 looks as follows:

```
envelopesApi.createRecipientView(accountId, envelopeId, recipientView  ...
```

If I use the REST API I get a successful view URL, so I know the parameters I pass are correct.

Comment: Please post the actual request body you're code is generating (the actual JSON) so we can inspect.

Comment: Well I don't have any control over how the request body looks like, I am using the SDK. Am I correct in saying the method signature changed between version 2 and version 3?

Comment: What do you mean, it's an open source library.  You can at least print the envelope definition as that's what we mostly need, just convert it to JSON and print to console then copy that and post in your question.

Comment: When I tested the API online, everything worked perfect. The problem was that in V3 of the DocuSign Node Client V3 you have to wrap your JSON with `recipientViewRequest` that I could not find in the documentation. Maybe I just missed it.

Comment: I would appreciate comments with a down vote as to why. I would like to understand and learn.

Answer (score -1):

The third parameter to the createRecipientView is wrapped as follow in the DocuSign Node Client (SDK V3):

```
envelopesApi.createRecipientView(accountId, envelopeId, {'recipientViewRequest': recipientView}, ...
```